# Java SE HTML POST filename issue

Tags: java, file-upload, filenames, html-post, nanohttpd

I'm currently writing a program using nanoHTTPD to upload files to a server. Currently I can successfully upload the file with a preassigned name. However, I would like to maintain the original name of the file being uploaded.

How it uploads now:

```
Original filename: foo.jpg
Uploaded filename: file123.whatever
```

How I want it to upload:

```
Original file name: foo.jpg
Uploaded filename: foo.jpg
```

Here is the HTML being used:

```
  <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="/uploaded.html" METHOD=POST>
Upload a file: <INPUT NAME="userfile1" TYPE="file">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File">
</FORM>
```

Here is the vanilla nanoHTTPD code for reference: http://pastebin.com/pMNS3VKf

Note: I would prefer to use Java SE and avoid Java EE.

Any advice would be welcomed, thank you.

Edit: in short all I need to learn how to do is get the filename from the HTML POST.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain if your NanoHTTPD is the same as mine, but with mine you can retrieve the original filename by looking at the parms Parameters object for the same key that you retrieve the file from the files Parameters object.

```
Enumeration<Object> keys = files.keys()
while (keys.hasMoreElements())
    {
    String key = keys.nextElement().toString();
    String origFileName = parms.getProperty(key);
    String fsFileName = files.getProperty(key);
    this.renameFile(fsFileName, origFileName);
    }
```

Once you retrieve the filename, you can use whatever method you want to rename the file. (With proper checking. It could be a huge security hole if you completely trusted their original filename.)